# How to stop a custom jQuery function when a certain condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a mobile navigation plugin. In order to run it I have to call the function like this **$(#nav).easyPie();**

Now I only want to call this function when the screen size/browser window size is less than 757px. In order to do this I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 757) {
            $('#site-content-sidebar').addClass('acs');
             $('#subnav').easyPie();
            } 
        else {
          $('#site-content-sidebar').removeClass('acs');
          // This is where I need a way to say stop easyPie();
        }
    });
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 757) {
             $('#site-content-sidebar').addClass('acs');
             $('#subnav').easyPie();
        } 
    else {
      $('#site-content-sidebar').removeClass('acs');
      // This is where I need a way to say stop easyPie();
    }
 });
```

In the else statement (when the screen size is more than 757px) I want the easyPie(); function to stop running/executing if it is running. How can I do this?

Comment: I can't find the plugin you are talking about. Can you share the official page? You can find there the methods to destroy, initialize, etc

Comment: Here is the GitHub page for the plugin 
https://github.com/chrisdivyak/EasyAsPie

Comment: can you put lower if/else statements before resize event handler and try ?

Comment: Also looking at its code, easypie already seems have to  resize event handler. I don't think you need to specify your own.

Comment: @gurvinder372 that does not change anything. the problem is that the jquery script is modifying my html when it is run at lower than 757px. and when i resize the window size to greater than 757px the modified html is there in my page now. I think maybe instead of using the resize i should use another way to do this.